# EVE Online Gunnery Simulator?

Tags: eve-online

I'm interested in doing some theorycraft around signature radius, transversal velocity, and mismatched-class PvP in EVE Online.  I'm sure someone's built tools to show the effects on damage from various factors in EVE combat (frigate sig radius vs. battleship guns, etc, etc).

I'm looking for a tool that lets me put in some numbers and does the math for me (excepting, perhaps, some basic trig for figuring out the angular velocity of a target vessel). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

Eve Fitting Tool (EFT) can simulate two ships with their respective fittings, and also what speed they are going relative to each other as well and will show you DPS graphs based on Range. It has been able to do this for quite a few versions now.

To find the latest version of EFT, take a look on this forum post http://www.eveonline.com/ingameboard.asp?a=topic&threadid=548883

Once you have EFT load up two different ship setup windows and fit them out appropriately. One will be your "attacker" ship and one will be your "target" ship. Both ship setup windows need to stay open. Now click File -> New DPS Graph. In the white box on the right of the graph, right click and select Add Attacker -> (choose the ship setup you'll be attacking with). In the same box, right click and Select Add Target -> (choose the ship setup you'll be trying to kill).

Now you get a pretty graph. You can adjust relative velocities down the bottom right. To simulate a common scenario : Make the targets arrow point away from the attacker circle at %100 (Target tries to run away), Make the attacker's arrow go straight up or down perpendicular to the other circle (attacker establishes orbit). The graph will bend and move to show how this affects.

You can also switch to your open fit and switch out your ammo to close or long range ammo and watch how it affects the DPS at different ranges. Or if you really feel, you can duplicate the open attacker fit, name it something slightly different and open it in a new window, now change the ammo or whatever other fittings you like on the new setup and add that as a separate attacker. Now you have two graphs overlaid.

Comment: Is there specific instructions as to how to set this up? If so, I'll give you an upvote. :)

Comment: @qoonpooka : there we go, added a bunch of info about how to set up DPS graphs. If that still leaves you confused, comment @me again and I'll try to clear it up. Also, thanks @sir k for adding in the link i missed :)

Comment: I will give this a try, if it meets my needs I'll let you know! Sounds promising!

Answer (score 4):

If I recall correctly, EFT will give average DPS when you correctly fill in the target's properties (sig radius, damage resists, etc), but I don't think there was any way to have it work with moving targets.

The equations seem to be fairly straightforward, however, so you should be able to plug them all into Excel or the like to get fairly good estimates.  The equation at the EVE Wiki page [Turret Damage](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Turret_damage) includes signature resolution/radius, tracking/traversal speed, target range, and turret optimal/falloff range.

If you un-fubar the single-line equation on the page, I think it looks like this:

[image]

Where:

- *D* is the range
- *d* is the size
- *ω* is the (angular) speed
- *p<sub>hit</sub>* ends up determining things like if it hits at all and/or if it's a 'wrecking' hit (see the article for details)

I tried looking for spreadsheets on the forums, but all the ones I found were gone (deleted off share sites).

Comment: I can't find the means by which I put target information into EFT.  I figured out how to do that to calculate my own tank and EHP just fine, though.  Moving targets are, in fact, my issue.

Comment: Thank you for un-fubaring that equation!  In particular I'm interested in looking at the extent to which sig radius plays a role and low-speeds.  I understand that a stationary target gets no benefit from its sig radius and takes full damage - but I don't know if a small sig (say an inty) gets its full sig radius effect if it's moving at 1m/sec, for example.  (While irrelevant for inties, this makes a HUGE difference in how you'd fly a Maulus or Griffin, say.)

Answer (score 0):

EFT was a great tool, but is not supported anymore. Use Pyfa:

https://github.com/pyfa-org/Pyfa/releases - for download
https://wiki.eveuniversity.org/PYFA - for instructions